# Add views from SharedPrefs with a loop

Tags: java, android

I have 2 fragments with separated lifecycles, I want to add permanent views into fragment1 by clicking on a button in fragment2, the best way I've came up with is using shared preferences.

**fragment1:**

```
int i;

do {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, i*10, 0, 0);
    Schedule_Class mClass = new Schedule_Class(getActivity(), "Math");
    Container.addView(mClass, params);

    } while (prefs.getString("mClass"+i++, null) != null);
```

**fragment2:**

```
int i;
    FinishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            prefs.edit().putString("mClass" + i++, "dummyValue").apply();
        }
    });
```

What's happening is, it's only adding one view with the latest key value, the prvious one just gets replaced.

**Question:**

Why is this loop not working as intended? How do I make it work?

Comment: What is the value of **i** present in onClickListener of finish button?

Comment: **i** is the int that diferenciates every key by adding a diffrent number to each one

Comment: If you are incrementing the **i** which is not defined in the onClick method and if this variable is not a global instance, it will be a final variable. This may be reason behind the issue. Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `for loop` is a good way to do this

```
for (i = 1; prefs.getString("mClass"+i, null) != null; i++ ){

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, i*10, 0, 0);
    Schedule_Class mClass = new Schedule_Class(getActivity(), "Math");
    Container.addView(mClass, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you trigger the code in Fragment1 when you click finishButton in Fragment2?

Generally speaking, you can use some event framework such as EventBus.

Comment: I add a value into a key string by clicking on it, and check if that key is null or not, if not it adds a view

Answer (score 0):

you can work with the logic of  LISTVIEW,, you can bloat the  the fagment,  one time, and the second time, you can  put other  desing  above BaseAdapter , 
some logic from  oficla web site.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

and other example from  internet(google)

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but some of the views may need to overlay